# Query complexity vs code complexity

Tags: sql, database, hibernate

So my question is rather simple, what's better and faster, doing calculations in code(let's say java) or just doing complex database queries(if we assume we can do one same action in both ways)? Which approach is better in general, and why?

Comment: ask yourself, which one is reusable and who own business logic (database or java code or both).

Comment: Faster to develop or faster to execute?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do in the code.

Doing business calculations in the queries in the DB gets the logic of the app spread and not easly understandable, plus you often get bound to specific storage (i.e. SQL Server/Oracle/MySql/etc) leaving the possibility to chage storage paradigma (i.e. to a NoSQL DB). 
Then in the code you can apply some injection to change easly the behavior of your code, making it more manageable.

Comment: For exactly the same reasons, I recommend doing it in SQL.

Comment: Can you motivate?

Comment: Business logic on the data should be stored *with* the data so all users see the same logic.  Similarly, data integrity checks should be in the database -- that is one of the things that databases do.  I spend too much of my life dealing with business logic in applications that changes over time.

Comment: I can understand you motivations, even if I don't agree totally. Ok for the integrity checks, but not for the business logic (imho)

Answer (score 0):

I generally find it faster (in development time) to write a query to do what I need. The first round focuses on logical correctness, and I'll complete the rest of the functionality using that query. I try to avoid doing queries in loops in this phase, but otherwise I don't worry too much about performance.

Then, I'll look at the performance of the whole feature. If the query is too slow, I'll EXPLAIN it and look at the server's statistics. My first focus is on indexes, if that doesn't work I'll try restructuring the query. Sometimes correlated subqueries are faster than joins, sometimes unions are faster than disjunctions in the WHERE clause, sometimes it's the other way around.

If I can't get satisfactory performance using a single query, I may break it up into multiple queries and/or do some of the work in code. Such code tends to be more complicated and longer than an equivalent query, so I try to avoid it unless necessary.